# Swift renaming the back navigation item

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I'm trying to edit the tile of the **back item** in the navigation controller.

I have this scene, **Navigation Controller -> Table View Controller -> TableViewController**.

In the second TableViewController I want to rename the the back item from "*xxxx*" to "*Back*".

Is there a way to do via the **StoryBoard**, or should I do it **programmatically**?

This is what I've tried but it does not work:

```
let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
backItem.title = "Back"
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem? = backItem
```

or

```
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.title = "back"
```

both of them in the viewDidLoad()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, you can do that with `StoryBoard`. Select the `NavgationItem` in `TableViewController` that you have embedded in `NavgationController` after that in  the `Attribute Inspector` set the `Back Button` with title that you want in your case it is `Back`.

[image]

Comment: I've tried to do as you said, but it does not work :(

Comment: @TheMiotz Are you sure that you are setting this Back button for the `FirstController` not for the `SecondController` ? If not read my answer once again because you need to set it for the first one

Comment: Well, I have just a navigation item, and it's in the FirstController.

Comment: @TheMiotz Then this will definitely work, have you pressed enter after setting back button title?

Comment: @TheMiotz Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 2):

The `backBarButtonItem` works for the view controller that you are going back **TO** not the one you are going back **FROM**.

So, in your case in the **first** view controller you can have the code...

```
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Some title", style: .done, target: nil, action: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.backBarButtonItem?.title = "back"
```