# How to remove the back title in navigationbar ?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

In navigation controller, I from `客户管理` push to `客户详情`.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

How can I hide the `客户管理`（navigationBar back button title）?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23853617/uinavigationbar-hide-back-button-text

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42973078/swift-renaming-the-back-navigation-item/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Add this code after @end in appDelegate :

```
@implementation UINavigationItem (additional)

-(UIBarButtonItem *)backBarButtonItem
    {
        return [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
    }
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

**In the interface builder**, you can select the navigation item of the previous controller and change the `Back Button` string to what you'd like the back button to appear as. *If you want it blank, for example, just put a space.*

You **can also change it** with this line of code:

`[self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Title here"];`

Or in **Swift**:

`self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.title = ""`

Comment: Can you explain the `select the navigation item of the previous controller and change the Back Button string ` mean ?

Comment: In the Storyboard you can change the title of the back button to be blank or do it via coding as mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide that for whole app then try this one:

```
extension UINavigationItem {
    func backBarButtonItem() -> UIBarButtonItem {
        return UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    }
}
```

And if you want to hide that for particular view then write below code.

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.title = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the title of that button as below

```
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.title = ""
```

Also, if you are looking to hide it everywhere you can create an extension for UINavigationController.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that but easiest way that always works without any problem is:

```
let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
backItem.title = " "
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem
```

You just need to copy and paste this code inside your viewDidLoad.